# How to register hibernate interceptor in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, interceptor

I need to register class which is derived from EmptyInterceptor in Spring. Do someone know how to register this interceptor to Hibernate session? Definition of my SesionFactory is bellow.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.foo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to register an interceptor you have to use entityInterceptor property. Please try :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.foo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="foo.bar.MyInterceptor"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```